# Macro to Copy-Paste between a Data Workbook and a Plot Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am fairly new to coding macros in excel VBA and I am in need of some help. I have 2 different workbooks that I am working with. One has data sets on multiple sheets and one has plots that correspond to those data sets. I am looking for a macro that will allow for me to copy columns D-I from the active sheet in the data workbook and will paste it into the active sheet in the plot workbook. The tricky part that I am trying to achieve is I want the data to be pasted to the plot workbook based on a corresponding date column (column a in plot workbook and column b in data workbook).

The reason for the 2 workbooks is the plots are a template and this is the easiest way I have been able to come up with to keep all the plots to look exactly the same except for the various data. I have over a hundred of these plots to do so anything that will speed up the transfer process would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
NOTE: Make sure that you open each workbook in only 1 instance of Excel.
      EX: Open Dataworkbook.xls
          From the file menu open next workbook
          From the file menu open next workbook
          etc.

The following is the code:

```
    Option Explicit

    'NOTE: This should be called from your main data Workbook
    Sub RunIT()

      '                             'Sheet that data is on
      '                                              'Range matrix to copy
      '                                                        'Workbook
      '                                                                     'Range to copy to
      DataPaste ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:E10"), "Book1.xls", "E1"
      DataPaste ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:E10"), "Book2.xls", "E1"

    End Sub

    Sub DataPaste(rngFrom As Range, strToWorkbook As String, strToRange As String)
        Dim shtSheet As Worksheet
        Dim wndw As Window
        Dim wbTo As Workbook
        Dim wbItem As Workbook

        'Initialize copy event
        rngFrom.Copy

        strToWorkbook = LCase(Trim(strToWorkbook))
        'loop through each workbook that is open in this instance of Excel
        For Each wbItem In Application.Workbooks
            'If Names match then, copy data
            If LCase(Trim(wbItem.Name)) = strToWorkbook Then
                'This loops through all sheets in specified workbook(CopyTo).
                For Each shtSheet In wbItem.Worksheets
                    'Paste it
                    shtSheet.Paste shtSheet.Range(strToRange)
                Next
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```